# Принимаемые значения в методе Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, методы, model, model-view

Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно понимать эту конструкцию:

```
 fun bind(
        cardModel: CardModel, deleteFromCard: (CardModel) -> Unit,
        moreCount: (CardModel) -> Unit, lessCount: (CardModel) -> Unit
    )
```

Unit, насколько я знаю - это тоже самое, что и viod в java

а что означает lessCount: (CardModel) - это что, создание метода, в качестве принимаемого значения в методе или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types

Answer (score -1, accepted):

в Котлине это называется "опциональный тип".
по сути - это тот же интерфейс-колбэк. только не надо мучаться, чтобы объявлять отдельный интерфейс.

да, можно сказать что это "метод-аргумент". вызывать его можно либо
`lessCount()` или `lessCount.invoke()`

в данном коде вы могли создать либо 1 интерфейс с 3 методами и передавать объект этого интерфейса.
можно было создать по 1 интерфейсу с 1им методом и передавать 3 объекта.
а можно и так, как сделано, через опциональный тип.

Comment: Не "опциональный тип", а функциональный тип или лямбда https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html. Я вообще не слышал про "опциональный тип" в котлине. Гугл выдаёт на "опциональный тип" swift с фичей, аналогичной nullable-типам в kotlin